# How to verify service account users for the Webmaster Tools API

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, google-search-console

I have an application that creates sites, including registering the domain and configuring the DNS.  When a site is created, I'd like to add the domain to Google Webmaster Tools and add a sitemap to the domain.

I'm using the new [Webmasters Service](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/a414aceb0af4da17240f0c17df097ecd841d17e8/src/Google/Service/Webmasters.php) in the Google API PHP Client with a service account.  Authentication is done with a Service Account and OAuth2 as described in [the docs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/aaa_oauth2_service); this works to some extent in that I can add a site and access the list of sites to confirm that it has been added, but the permission level for the site is "siteUnverifiedUser" and, with that level of access, attempting to also add a site map triggers an HTTP 403 error "(403) User does not have sufficient permission for site".

Earlier versions of the API [seemed to support verification](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#AD_Verifying), but that has been removed and the documentation no longer mentions it.  How can I go about verifying that my service account has access to the domain so that I can add sitemaps to it?

Comment: Aaaand just like that I find the [site verification api](https://developers.google.com/site-verification/v1/getting_started)... I'll dig more and see whether this resolves things for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to this is that Google's [Site Verification API](https://developers.google.com/site-verification/v1/getting_started) can be used to verify ownership of the site, then other operations like adding sitemaps will also be permitted.